# How do I modify sys.path from .htaccess to allow mod_python to see Django?

Tags: python, django, apache, .htaccess, mod-python

The host I'm considering for hosting a Django site has mod_python installed, but does not have Django. Django's INSTALL file indicates that I can simply copy the django directory to Python's site-packages directory to install Django, so I suspect that it might be possible to configure Python / mod_python to look for it elsewhere (namely my user space) by modifying sys.path, but I don't know how to change it from .htaccess or mod_python.

**How do I modify `sys.path` from `.htaccess` to allow mod_python to see Django?**

P.S. I can only access the site via FTP (i.e. no shell access). I realize that it sounds like I should just switch hosts, but there are compelling reasons for me to make this work so I'm at least going to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [ticket #2255](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2255) for Django, you need admin access to httpd.conf in order to use Django with mod_python, and this is not going to change, so you may be dead in the water.  To answer the basic question of how to modify `sys.path` from `.htaccess`, you can use the [PythonPath](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/dir-other-pp.html) directive in `.htaccess`.

Comment: It looks like that ticket is from 2006... hopefully things have changed since then. I guess I'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Is the [PythonPath](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/dir-other-pp.html) setting what you are looking for? I haven't tried it with Django, but I would assume that it should do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're using mod_python wrong. It was never intended to serve python web applications. You should be using WSGI for this... or at least FastCGI.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I'm constrained by what the host provides.