# Deploying a Django website without access to httpd.conf (with or without mod_wsgi)

Tags: django, apache, deployment

Can I deploy a django app with only write permissions in a particular folder on the server?

For a recent work, I asked the admin to modify the .conf for me (and install mod_wsgi which was not present), but it would have been much less painful if I could have deployed the app by just uploading the files. (on apache)

I don't have much experience with Django, it was my first site, so I'm hoping that it's possible. The [official documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/#howto-deployment-index) did not mention it though, but hey, StackOverflow may know better :).

Thanks

Edit: I finished this particular job, only hope for the future to have easier deployment.

Edit2: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491102/deploying-django-to-userdir) seems like a "nearly-exact" duplicate, so I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491102/deploying-django-to-userdir instructive. The answer is basically "probably not".

Comment: Thank you. (why 15 characters)

Answer (score 0):

fast_cgi is the only other sensible possibility, does the apache have that module loaded?

can you run your own lighttpd or nginx or something and have the apache do a proxy rewrite to it?

If you can't modify the .conf, you'll have to set it up in the .htaccess file

Comment: Unfortunately I can't run another webserver in most cases.

Comment: FASTCGI still needs an administrator to set it up initially even if you can then add files into directories. There are ways of having administrator set up mod_wsgi once for a user then allow them to just add files into directories without the administrator having to do further work. With mod_wsgi it isn't as flexible in this respect as FASTCGI, but still possible.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton: This should be an answer not a comment, so I can upvote or accept it :).

Comment: I wasn't providing an answer on how to do it with mod_wsgi but just highlighting that FASTCGI solutions are also going to need access to main configuration to at least set up. So, just additional information to this persons response. Yon can still up vote a comment. Hover to left of comment and see up arrow appear.

Comment: related to gnibbler's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764312/how-do-i-modify-sys-path-from-htaccess-to-allow-mod-python-to-see-django